# Find Cameron-Martin space of known process

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, wiener-measure

Find Cameron-Martin space of process $W_t-4tW_1$, where $W_t$ is Wiener process.
As I know the definition of Cameron-Martin space is:
$$H(\gamma)=\left\{ h \in X :|h|_{H(\gamma)}:= \sup_{\substack{f\in X^*} \\ {||f||_{L^2} \leq 1}}f(h)\lt \infty\right\} $$
Also I found out that this process is gaussian.
But I can't figure out what should I do with it.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I tried to find gaussian measure